# How to send a Firebase Cloud message from device to device on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm going through [Firebase's FCM tutorial for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream), and I can't seem to send a simple message from one device to another.

Here's my code:

`user1token` is the token of the user I'm sending the notification to (I've printed the token to confirm it works).

```
val message = RemoteMessage.Builder(user1token)
    .addData("user2name", "zorgan")
    .build()
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message)
```

I've tested this code while user1 is in the background and they don't receive a notification.

If I look at the tutorial code, it doesn't contain any mention of the receivers token...:

```
val fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
fm.send(RemoteMessage.Builder("$SENDER_ID@fcm.googleapis.com")
        .setMessageId(Integer.toString(messageId))
        .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
        .addData("my_action", "SAY_HELLO")
        .build())
```

so this seems wrong? How can you send a message to a device with only a sender's token.

Any idea what the problem is?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream

Comment: Do you want to send notification while app is in background?

Comment: Yes while the app is in background or foreground.

Comment: The documentation is saying that you need an XMPP server to work with upstream messages.  Do you have an application server that understands XMPP messaging?

Comment: Ah yes I just discovered this page which says I need a server: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol I'll read into this. thanks.